# Are there any commands to do after a LARAVEL deployment?

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel back end (5.5) which runs fine in my local machine.

I deployed this back end for the 1st time (with Jenkins and Rancher). And it worked, perfect!

I made some changes on my local machine and made a new deployment. But now after this deployment I have some problems with routes. I have a this error:

> BadMethodCallException: Method [index2] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\BlocController]. in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php

I checked on production: the routing file and controller file are exactly the same between my local machine and my production. So I do not understand why I have this error in production.

Are there any commands to do after a deployment? It seems that my production keeps older things in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deployed it on a linux machine check the namespace names, as they are case sensitive in linux.

run:

```
php artisan config:clear  => clears config and cache at the same time 

php artisan route:clear   => clears cached routes

composer dump-autoload    => autoload the classes
```

Comment: Thanks leo. When I entered these 3 commands I had an error : I had the same controller name in 2 different files. I deleted the doublon, republished again and now the problem is solved. I do not know why I have not this error on my local machine. Merci

Comment: @Dom happens ! np